# can't understand the url function used in the google taskque api documentation

Tags: java, google-app-engine

> import
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.Queue;
>   import
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueFactory;
>   import static
>   com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.*;
>
> // ...
>           Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
>           queue.add(url("/worker").param("key",
>   key))

in the code example given on the google task queue documentation page i can't understand the url("/worker") function they are calling in the queues.add() invocation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is the URL that will be called to execute the task. AppEngine is very URL-oriented, and the task that is executed by the task queue is referred to by a URL.

From the docs:

> App Engine applications can perform
>   background processing by inserting
>   tasks (modeled as web hooks) into a
>   queue.

The key point here is **web hooks**. Google can help you with web hooks.